# How to put information from one database to a spesific form in another in Lotus notes

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus-formula

The aim is: to create two DB in the first should be information about all cities and streets, in another there should be an opportunity to fulfill the name, middle name and to choose town and street from the first DB. The problem is that I really don't understand how to put the information about town and street to this fields with an opportunity to choose.

Answer (score 1):

Why have it in two different databases? Who came up with that design?
But it is not very hard to do, it just depends on exactly how you want it to work, if it is a Notes client application or a web application, etc.

Check @DBColumn and @DbLookup in the help, or possibly the GetDocumentByKey method of the NotesView class if you are using Lotusscript.

I suggest that you take some classes in how to develop for Lotus Notes, or pick up a book.